# s3:PutObject Access Denied from CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-s3, deployment, permissions, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild

I am attempting to create a simple s3 hosted website and for building/deploying changes to the s3 bucket, I wanted to use CodePipeline with a CodeBuild step. When CodeBuild has created the production artifacts, I would just do

`aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./dist s3://my-hosting-bucket`

and then it would place everything I need into my hosting bucket. The problem is that when I run this command, I receive the following error:

`upload failed: dist/js/chunk-vendors.e598c2a4.js.map to s3://<my-bucket-name>/js/chunk-vendors.e598c2a4.js.map An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied Completed 831.9 KiB/977.4 KiB (0 Bytes/s) with 9 file(s) remaining`

If I copy/paste this command and run it with my user locally, it uploads the files without issue. I've created the proper roles and tried adding a bucket policy as well which allows the roles to write to the bucket, but nothing is working.

```
CodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "PipelineAccess"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Action: 
                - 's3:GetObject'
                - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                - 's3:GetBucketVersioning'
                - 's3:PutObject'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - Action:
                - 'codebuild:BatchGetBuilds'
                - 'codebuild:StartBuild'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'codecommit:GetRepository'
                - 'codecommit:ListRepositories'
                - 'codecommit:GetBranch'
                - 'codecommit:GetCommit'
                - 'codecommit:UploadArchive'
                - 'codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: !ImportValue RepoArn

CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [codebuild.amazonaws.com]
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "CodeBuildAccess"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                  - 's3:GetBucketVersioning'
                  - 's3:PutObject'
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                  - 's3:GetBucketVersioning'
                  - 's3:PutObject'
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                  - 'cloudfront:CreateInvalidation'
                Resource:
                  - "*"

CodeBuild:
    Type: "AWS::CodeBuild::Project"
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CodeBuild
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole 
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        Name: '/'
        Location: !Ref DeployBucket
        Path: 'dist/'
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        Image: "aws/codebuild/standard:5.0"
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
                - npm install
            build:
              commands:
                - echo Build starting on `date`
                - npm install -g @vue/cli
                - npm run build
            post_build:
              commands:
                - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./dist s3://${DeployBucket}/ --region us-east-2
          artifacts:
            files:
              - '**/*'
            base-directory: build

Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref 'ArtifactBucket'
        Type: S3
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      Name: !Ref 'PipelineName'
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: CheckoutSource
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeCommit
              Configuration:
                PollForSourceChanges: true
                RepositoryName: !ImportValue Repo
                BranchName: master
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: App
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            -
              Name: BuildAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts:
                -
                  Name: App
              OutputArtifacts:
                -
                  Name: MyAppBuild
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
```

Here is the bucket Policy as well

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1624203",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt162424558",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/Pipeline-CodePipelineRole-4MZ4YYUIGCBT",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/Pipeline-CodeBuildRole-1SOSJXEILREIB"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<deploy bucket>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my codebuild role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Artifact bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Artifact bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<deploy bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<deploy bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems like I've given everything i possibly can permissions to upload this to s3, so not sure where I am going wrong

`Update`

I tried to update the bucket policy based on the comment from @StefanN but it did not work. Here is the new bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1624202574423",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1624202534558",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "<bucket arn>/*",
                "<bucket arn>"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": "<role id>:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think in your bucket policy you need to set allow principal:* and then limit with condition to your specific role. Check out this article, where I described a similar issue https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-locked-the-whole-company-out-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket-1781de51e4be

Comment: updated the bucket policy but didn't work. I'm wondering, should I have an instance profile for the role, or just the role arn? It seems like I shouldn't since i'm having codebuild assume the role, and the role has the policy attached to it which allows for s3:PutObject to this bucket

Comment: You just want the role's ARN. BTW Instance profile is just a proxy (or a container) which enables assigning roles to instances.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it was actually because I needed to have permission to Put an ACL as well as an object

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that because I am setting a public read ACL with the CLI command, I needed to add that permission as well. Here is my final bucket ACL

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1624611947939",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1624611923175",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/Pipeline-CodeBuildRole-1SOSJXEILREIB"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now everything is working.